# $z_0 = 0$ a branch point for $f(z) =(z + i)^{\frac{1}{2}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

I seem to have a mental block regarding branch points...I thought that the singularities of a function determined its branch points but then I read that they are irrelevant when deciding if a point is a branch point of some function? I.e. $\frac{1}{z^2}$ has a singularity at $0$ but it has no branch points.

Suppose $f(z) = z^\frac{1}{2}$. Then $z_0 = 0$ is a branch point for $f(z)$.

But suppose we had $f(z) = (z + i)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Why is $z_0 = 0$ not a branch point for $f(z)$ in this case? What is it about $f(z)$ that determines it's branch point(s)? How can I determine the branch points for $f(z) = (z + i)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Short answer: because $0 + i = i$, and $i$ is not a branch-point of the square root. For a longer answer, it would be nice to know what concepts you are [moderately] familiar with. Does the phrase "analytic continuation along a curve" mean something to you, or does it sound like a random concatenation of letters?

Comment: If let $z=re^{\theta\pi i}$ and $z_1=re^{\theta\pi i + 2\pi i}$, clearly $z=z_1$ if $f(z)$ is not equal to $f(z_1)$ then $z$ is a braching point.